# A type of long-term memory where I can remember full dialogues

Tags: memory, long-term-memory

My female colleague cannot remember a discussion (dialogue) from a couple days ago or even yesterday, much less the full, exact sentences spoken. She jokes about having sclerosis. I can remember many dialogues from the last couple of years and even further, including the exact sentences – not all the dialogues from my life, but like 80% of those which were interesting, odd, or very funny, or made at least small impact in my life. Is this kind of long memory normal in people? Does it have a name?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you read [The Mind of a Mnemonist](http://www.amazon.com/The-Mind-Mnemonist-Little-Memory/dp/0674576225)?

Comment: @osa nope, but I will. Thanks for a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the cognitive skills of a human population have a great variance. I am more like your friend, with episodic memory below average but semantic memory above average. You seem to have episodic memory above average (I envy you on that, because a large part of our feeling of self identity depends on episodic memory). There are extreme cases of people that remember almost everything they experience or read, or hear. A nice book on the topic is Luria's book "the mind of a mnemonist". It is a short book, and I'm sure you'll find it pretty interesting.

Comment: "a large part of our feeling of self identity depends on episodic memory" --- this is a limiting belief that makes you less happy.

Answer (score 1):

The remembering of specific events is known as [Episodic memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episodic_memory), and you can find plenty about it online. It's usually contrasted with [Semantic memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_memory), which is generalized knowledge such as that "Paris is the capital of France".

---

I'm going to leave it to other users, or myself at a later date, to provide additional references/explanation, but those are the terms you're looking for.